# Integral form of legendre polynomial of second kind

Tags: legendre-polynomials

I found a definite integral form of Legendre polynomial of second kind,
$$
Q_{n}(z)=\frac{1}{2}\int^{+1}_{-1}\frac{P_{n}(t)}{z-t}dt 
$$
when n is an integer.
I wonder how to evaluate this integral. I tried to use contour integral by changing $t$ to $e^{i\theta}$, but it failed.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: This is pretty much a *definition* of the Legendre *function* of the second kind. So you're asking for an expression for $Q_n(z)$. Which one?..